# Why is /bin in the path?

Tags: linux, path

Now that almost all modern mainstream Linuxes and Unixes have `/bin` as a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`, why is it that by default the `PATH` contains `/usr/bin` followed by `/bin`? Will I break anything if I clean up my `PATH` by removing `/bin`? I assume it's there by default for compatibility reasons of some sort, but I can't think what.

Comment: See: [`man hier`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html)

Comment: Short answer: no one cares. Longer answer: file bug reports. We are talking about 6 bytes lost per running application. And 11 bytes for root applications. That's nothing.

Comment: Because "almost all" is not the same as "all", and nobody wants an upgrade to break systems that have been running for 5, 10, 20, or more years.   e.g. on one of my systems, `/bin/` has 204 files in it, while `/usr/bin/` has 7766.   Removing /bin (and /sbin) from the default $PATH would break that system as the executables in /bin and /sbin are essential during the early stages of booting up.    BTW, merging /bin and /usr/bin & /sbin with /usr/sbin was a stupid idea, it demonstrates a complete lack of understanding of why they were separate to begin with.

Comment: On your system, your can do whatever you like.   but changing an OS's long-standing defaults is dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned. The /bin folder is where the whole system user executable files used to reside on most systems.
But with time, */bin*, */sbin* and similar, have moved to the */usr* subfolder. Nowdays most systems create a link
*/bin -> /usr/bin*
this is just in case, if someone might run older shells versions, user scripts or simply hard coded paths in programs - all expecting to be working even if they haven't been updated for 10 or more years :)

As for the question should you remove it from the $PATH: If you are using a normal user account (and not f.e. root) and you are **sure** you won't run any program needing the */bin* - you can do it. The main question for you would be, does it really bother you if you keep it?

Comment: Oh I replied to the removing it in the PATH as well, but you are right, someone might understand removing system link. Will explain better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the ancient times, when *big* disks had a few MiB, Unix systems had their own executables/libraries, under `/bin`, `/lib` and so on. Users requested extra facilities, that weren't required to start the machine, and so got placed on the disk for users, perhaps a cheap, slow but larger one, `/usr`. Later disks got in the GiB range, machines got to be personal (my own computer, not the one of the university/department) started to have one disk only, which got subdivided (partitioned) into a small `/` and a (largeish) `/usr`; if any fluke damages the disk (or the data thereon), it was more probable that `/` survived (or a small "rescue" disk with it's contents) and could be used to fix the system. Today to segregate between "system essential" and "nice to have" binaries makes little sense (nowadays you can stash a full installation of most Linux distributions on a pendrive). If the filessytem layout was designed today, there probably would just be no `/usr` at all.